# Are there any free prior art search services?

Tags: prior-art

I found a website (C-DAC) in India that performs prior art searches for free. But, you have to live in India to register and request for a search. Are there any other prior art search services for free?

Answer (score 0):

patents.google.com has an 'find Prior art' button. Have you tried it? 
It doesn't do the best job but it provides helpful first steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few key resources:
Patexia Patent Database

The United States Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO):

World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO):

European Patent Office (EPO):
EPO offers information about patents in Europe, including Espacenet, a searchable database of  more than 70 million patent documents worldwide, from 1836 to today.